# Karaf 4 bootfeature is not working

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

We upgraded from Karaf-3 to Karaf-4.0.10 version to move to Nitrogen version of Opendaylight. We are getting following exception while trying to start standard and application feature (custom-odl) as boot feature. However we are able to manually install the same custom-odl (not as bootfeature) feature through karaf console. In Karaf-3, we were able to start manually as well as bootfeature.

```
2018-02-26 14:50:58,266 | ERROR | 69e-e623d6584878  | 6 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.10 | BootFeaturesInstaller | Error installing boot features
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire the state change lock for the module: osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.apache.karaf.features.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.0.10" [id=6] STOPPED [STARTED]
```

org.apache.karaf.features.cfg (configuration file input)

> featuresBoot= (wrap), (standard), custom-odl

custom-odl has more than 100 bundles grouped under different features.

Answer (score 2):

The automated test jobs in upstream OpenDaylight are ok with featuresBoot. One
example I have is like this:

```
featuresBoot = odl-infrautils-ready,odl-netvirt-openstack, \
     standard, \
     wrap
```

maybe try your custom distribution without your custom features to make
sure that works. If that works, then possibly the problem is somewhere in
your custom feature.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do we need to follow the same order as how you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, i believe the issue is with my custom-odl feature, am able to install odl-infrautils* without any issues. Could you please tell me the difference of installing a feature as bootFeature and manual installation of the feature using feature:install command. I am able to install custom-odl feature manually

Comment: I'm not sure what internal difference there is between the two methods for installing features (maybe check the karaf documentation?), other than featuresBoot means they will be installed automatically when you start karaf. obviously, the other way is manual and done after you start karaf.

Comment: The difference is that featuresBoot will install all the listed features together - when you install manually via the CLI they are done one at a time.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Please let me know whether my understanding is correct. I have feature A which includes multiple features (B,C) and some bundles, so if i install feature-A from CLI it will install each feature seperately one after another. If we make feature-A as bootfeature then it will install  all sub features simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

That error indicate it's trying to acquire the lock to stop the bundle, ie it's trying to transition to the STOPPED state and the previous stateTransitionEvents were STARTED. There's something nasty going on - it seems like it may be trying to restart the bundle recursively. As Jamo mentioned, it's likely related to your custom-odl feature - I would suggest examining the feature and try adding pieces of it one at a time to find the offending part.